# errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed al crear una tabla

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo la siguiente sentencia SQL que me da el fallo

```
CREATE TABLE EventosCalendario (
  EvenCalen_idEvenCalen INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EvenCalen_inici DATE,
  EvenCalen_fin DATE,
  TipEven_idTipEven INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Tit_IdTitulaciones INTEGER NULL,
  AnoAc_idannoacademico INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EvenCalen_comentario VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  EvenCalen_fechaact TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(EvenCalen_idEvenCalen),
  INDEX TipEven_idTipEven USING BTREE (TipEven_idTipEven),
  INDEX AnoAc_idannoacademico USING BTREE (AnoAc_idannoacademico),
INDEX Tit_IdTitulaciones USING BTREE (Tit_IdTitulaciones),
  FOREIGN KEY (TipEven_idTipEven) REFERENCES TipoEvento (TipEven_idTipEven) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (Tit_IdTitulaciones) REFERENCES titulaciones (Tit_IdTitulaciones) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  FOREIGN KEY (AnoAc_idannoacademico) REFERENCES anosacademicos (AnoAc_idannoacademico) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo te falto la sentencia **CONSTRAINT**  seguido del nombre que tendrá la llave foránea (estos nombres deben de ser únicos)

Simplemente agrega **CONSTRAINT `FK1`** antes de cada **FOREIGN KEY**

La sentencia te quedaria algo asi:

```
CREATE TABLE EventosCalendario(
  EvenCalen_idEvenCalen INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EvenCalen_inici DATE,
  EvenCalen_fin DATE,
  TipEven_idTipEven INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Tit_IdTitulaciones INTEGER NULL,
  AnoAc_idannoacademico INTEGER NOT NULL,
  EvenCalen_comentario VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  EvenCalen_fechaact TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(EvenCalen_idEvenCalen),
  INDEX TipEven_idTipEven USING BTREE (TipEven_idTipEven),
  INDEX AnoAc_idannoacademico USING BTREE (AnoAc_idannoacademico),
INDEX Tit_IdTitulaciones USING BTREE (Tit_IdTitulaciones),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1` FOREIGN KEY (TipEven_idTipEven) REFERENCES TipoEvento (TipEven_idTipEven) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK2` FOREIGN KEY (Tit_IdTitulaciones) REFERENCES titulaciones (Tit_IdTitulaciones) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK3` FOREIGN KEY (AnoAc_idannoacademico) REFERENCES anosacademicos (AnoAc_idannoacademico) ON DELETE  RESTRICT ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Te dejo el codigo completo aqui:

**https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=6dd613de6e620e8805e198864d6e9b79**

Comment: Muchas gracias,

Comment: Ya lo probaste? te funciono?

Comment: Disculpa, si, me ha funcionado. Muchísimas gracias.